# AngularJs Directive get radio button ng-model value on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created an Angular js Directive that loops through ng-repeat and if users chooses any of those radio button, it should alert the current ng-model value.

But its not working. Please help.

```js
var someapp = angular.module('someapp', []);

someapp.controller('someappCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  //...

}).directive('checkthemChoice', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<label ng-repeat="choice in choices" for="{{ choice }}"><input type="radio" ng-checked="$first" name="selecttable" ng-model="radioSelected" value="{{ choice }}" id="{{ choice }}"> {{ choice }}</label>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.choices = ['organization', 'user'];

      element.on('change', function() {
        //this selected the parent DIV checkthem
        //but I want select the radio input inside LABEL
      });

      scope.$watch('radioSelected', function(val) {
        //this doesnt work
        alert(val);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="someapp" ng-controller="someappCtrl">

  <div class="checkthem" checkthem-Choice=""></div>

</div>
```

Comment: I've been looking at this for a couple minutes now and what I notice that strikes me as odd is that the watch triggers before the value radioSelected even exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works.

**radioSelected** needs to be a property of an object (for example, **test**). The explanation is given here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Also, I have a put a test for **undefined** in the watch to avoid the first alert on load.

```js
var someapp = angular.module('someapp', []);

someapp.controller('someappCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  //...

}).directive('checkthemChoice', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<label ng-repeat="choice in choices" for="{{ choice }}"><input type="radio" ng-checked="$first" name="selecttable" ng-model="test.radioSelected" value="{{ choice }}" id="{{ choice }}"> {{ choice }}</label>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.choices = ['organization', 'user'];
      scope.test = {};
 
      element.on('change', function() {
        //this selected the parent DIV checkthem
        //but I want select the radio input inside LABEL
      });

      scope.$watch('test.radioSelected', function(val) {
        if (val !== undefined) alert(val);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="someapp" ng-controller="someappCtrl">

  <div class="checkthem" checkthem-Choice=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks also, i tried this. and it worked too.

`<div class="checkthem" checkthem-Choice="" ng-model="radioSelected"></div>`
 and on radio i referenced it back to parent `<input ng-model="$parent.radioSelected" />`

Comment: @STEEL Interesting. It doesn't seem like the right way of doing it but I couldn't give you a clear reason why. I'd recommend my solution as it is a bit cleaner.

Comment: Sure , it is Clean ;)